# Al apllicar join, merge ó concat, el DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

Dispongo de éste DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def crear_df_cotiz():
    rango = ['2014-01-01', '2014-02-01', '2014-03-01', '2014-04-01',
                   '2014-05-01', '2014-06-01', '2014-07-01', '2014-08-01',
                   '2014-09-01', '2014-10-01', '2014-11-01', '2014-12-01',
                   '2015-01-01', '2015-02-01', '2015-03-01', '2015-04-01',
                   '2015-05-01', '2015-06-01', '2015-07-01', '2015-08-01',
                   '2015-09-01', '2015-10-01', '2015-11-01', '2015-12-01',
                   '2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-03-01', '2016-04-01',
                   '2016-05-01', '2016-06-01']
    valores = [100.0,99.97,99.96,99.95,99.94,99.92,99.9,99.84,99.94,100.82,100.62,100.63,100.84,100.72,
               100.61,100.7,100.63,100.08,100.22,100.09,99.79,99.42,99.42,99.3,98.88,98.63,98.62,99.55,99.24,99.33]
    df_cotiz = pd.DataFrame(valores, index = rango)
    df_cotiz.reset_index(inplace = True)
    df_cotiz.columns = ["Date", "Close"]
    df_cotiz['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_cotiz['Date'], errors='coerce')
    df_cotiz.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
    return df_cotiz

df_cotiz = crear_df_cotiz()
df_cotiz.info()
```

Me devuelve:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 30 entries, 2014-01-01 to 2016-06-01
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   Close   30 non-null     float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 480.0 bytes
```

Creo un DataFrame con otro rango de fechas.

```
start_date = '2012-1-1'
end_date = '2016-06-01'

df_all_dates = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.date_range(start = start_date, end = end_date))
```

A continuación quiero conseguir otro DataFrame, con el rango total de fechas y las columnas de los dos DataFrames (df_cotiz y df_all_dates).  Aplico el método join().

```
df = df_all_dates.join(df_cotiz[['Close']], how = 'left').fillna(df_cotiz.iloc[0])
```

Me devuelve.
[image: imagen con join]

Vemos que no tiene etiqueta la columna de índice de filas. No conserva la etiqueta'Date'.

Pruebo a continuación con merge().

```
from functools import reduce
dfs = [df_all_dates, df_cotiz]
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,left_index=True, right_index=True), dfs)   
df_final[:3]
```

Me devuelve:
[image: merge]
No conserva la etiqueta ?Date' y no conerva las filas que van de 2012 a 2014.

Seguidamente pruebo con concat:

```
# Selección de DataFrames
df1 = df_all_dates
df2 = df_cotiz
df_concat = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df_concat[:3]
```

Me devuelve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columnaa índice de filas, tampoco conserva la etiqueta 'Date'

Se que puedo modificar el DataFrame resultante para dar nombre a ésta columna, haciendo, por ejemplo:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'index':'Date'},inplace=True)
df.set_index('Date')[:3]
```

Pero pienso que en los métodos anteriores, seguramente hay algún parámetro que se me escapa, que haría posible conservar dicha etiqueta. Agradeceré sugerencias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo que estás intentando hacer en código no refleja lo que explicas en la pregunta, es decir, son cosas un poco diferentes. Yo creo que al entender de donde se obtienen los diferentes datos para el `dataframe` resultante podrás ver lo que sucede con los intentos que haces.

Primer punto. Cuando creas tu segundo `dataframe`, estás creando un `dataframe` vacío, sin columnas, únicamente índices y además el índice no tiene nombre, por lo que se vería algo así:

```
2012-01-01
2012-01-02
2012-01-03
2012-01-04
2012-01-05
...
2016-05-28
2016-05-29
2016-05-30
2016-05-31
2016-06-01
1614 rows × 0 columns
```

Segundo punto. Cuando haces tus intentos con `join`, `merge` y `concat` estás "copiando" o agregando los elementos de tu primer `dataframe` sobre la el contenido del segundo `dataframe`. Como el `segundo` dataframe ya vimos que son únicamente índices y que no tiene nombre entonces por eso la columna de los índices no tiene nombre. Una prueba rápida asignando un nombre a tus índices del segundo `dataframe` hace visible lo que describo:

```
# Creamos una columna "Test Date" con los datos que pusiste en tu pregunta
# Y luego convertimos esa columna a índice
df_all_dates = pd.DataFrame({'Test Date': pd.date_range(start = start_date, end = end_date)}).set_index('Test Date')

# Hacemos join
# El dataframe base es df_all_dates
# El dataframe que se copiará sobre la base es df_cotiz
df = df_all_dates.join(df_cotiz[['Close']], how = 'left').fillna(df_cotiz.iloc[0])
print(df)
```

En el resultado se puede ver que la columna de los índices tiene el nombre "Test Date":

```
             Close
Test Date         
2012-01-01  100.00
2012-01-02  100.00
2012-01-03  100.00
2012-01-04  100.00
2012-01-05  100.00
...            ...
2016-05-28  100.00
2016-05-29  100.00
2016-05-30  100.00
2016-05-31  100.00
2016-06-01   99.33

[1614 rows x 1 columns]
```

Esto es porque al hacer `join`, el `dataframe` que se utiliza como base es como la "plantilla" del `dataframe` resultante y el `dataframe` del que se importarán/copiarán los datos únicamente aporta los datos de las columnas, estos incluyen sus respectivos nombres (Ojo, no del índice, de las columnas únicamente), en caso de tener columnas con nombres repetidos se pueden asignar sufijos para saber de que `dataframe` provienen los datos.

En los tres casos el `dataframe` que utilizas como base o "plantilla" es tu segundo `dataframe` y entonces al no tener nombre en los índices el `dataframe` resultante tampoco tendrá nombre en los índices.

Hay una forma más sencilla de hacer lo que deseas, que en realidad es simplemente cambiar el rango de fechas del índice, para eso puedes utilizar `date_range` y `reindex`.

**Nota:** Hice algunas modificaciones en otras secciones de tu código para reducir el número de líneas y optimizar la creación del primer `dataframe`.

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def crear_df_cotiz():
    # No se si necesites crear los valores de cada fecha de esta forma
    # pero podrías utilizar pd.date_range('2014-01-01', periods=30, freq='MS')
    # que haría lo mismo pero en una sola línea
    rango = ['2014-01-01', '2014-02-01', '2014-03-01', '2014-04-01',
                   '2014-05-01', '2014-06-01', '2014-07-01', '2014-08-01',
                   '2014-09-01', '2014-10-01', '2014-11-01', '2014-12-01',
                   '2015-01-01', '2015-02-01', '2015-03-01', '2015-04-01',
                   '2015-05-01', '2015-06-01', '2015-07-01', '2015-08-01',
                   '2015-09-01', '2015-10-01', '2015-11-01', '2015-12-01',
                   '2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-03-01', '2016-04-01',
                   '2016-05-01', '2016-06-01']
    valores = [100.0,99.97,99.96,99.95,99.94,99.92,99.9,99.84,99.94,100.82,100.62,100.63,100.84,100.72,
               100.61,100.7,100.63,100.08,100.22,100.09,99.79,99.42,99.42,99.3,98.88,98.63,98.62,99.55,99.24,99.33]
    
    # Reduje el código de esta sección, hace lo mismo pero en menos filas
    df_cotiz = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rango, 'Close':valores}).set_index('Date')
    df_cotiz.index = pd.to_datetime(df_cotiz.index)
    return df_cotiz

df_cotiz = crear_df_cotiz()
print('Dataframe original:')
print(df_cotiz)

# Definir fecha de inicio y final
start_date = '2012-01-01'
end_date = '2016-06-01'

# Crear un rango con las nuevas fechas para el nuevo índice
# Usamos MS (Month Start) para que sea el primer día de cada mes
# Si quisieras que se hiciera un periodo por día puedes utilziar freq='D'
new_index = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='MS', name='Date')

# Cambiamos el periodo del dataframe original y rellenamos con NaN
df = df_cotiz.reindex(new_index, fill_value=None)
print('Dataframe resultante:')
print(df)
```

Esto imprime:

```
Dataframe original:
             Close
Date              
2014-01-01  100.00
2014-02-01   99.97
2014-03-01   99.96
2014-04-01   99.95
2014-05-01   99.94
2014-06-01   99.92
2014-07-01   99.90
2014-08-01   99.84
2014-09-01   99.94
2014-10-01  100.82
2014-11-01  100.62
2014-12-01  100.63
2015-01-01  100.84
2015-02-01  100.72
2015-03-01  100.61
2015-04-01  100.70
2015-05-01  100.63
2015-06-01  100.08
2015-07-01  100.22
2015-08-01  100.09
2015-09-01   99.79
2015-10-01   99.42
2015-11-01   99.42
2015-12-01   99.30
2016-01-01   98.88
2016-02-01   98.63
2016-03-01   98.62
2016-04-01   99.55
2016-05-01   99.24
2016-06-01   99.33
Dataframe resultante:
             Close
Date              
2012-01-01     NaN
2012-02-01     NaN
2012-03-01     NaN
2012-04-01     NaN
2012-05-01     NaN
2012-06-01     NaN
2012-07-01     NaN
2012-08-01     NaN
2012-09-01     NaN
2012-10-01     NaN
2012-11-01     NaN
2012-12-01     NaN
2013-01-01     NaN
2013-02-01     NaN
2013-03-01     NaN
2013-04-01     NaN
2013-05-01     NaN
2013-06-01     NaN
2013-07-01     NaN
2013-08-01     NaN
2013-09-01     NaN
2013-10-01     NaN
2013-11-01     NaN
2013-12-01     NaN
2014-01-01  100.00
2014-02-01   99.97
2014-03-01   99.96
2014-04-01   99.95
2014-05-01   99.94
2014-06-01   99.92
2014-07-01   99.90
2014-08-01   99.84
2014-09-01   99.94
2014-10-01  100.82
2014-11-01  100.62
2014-12-01  100.63
2015-01-01  100.84
2015-02-01  100.72
2015-03-01  100.61
2015-04-01  100.70
2015-05-01  100.63
2015-06-01  100.08
2015-07-01  100.22
2015-08-01  100.09
2015-09-01   99.79
2015-10-01   99.42
2015-11-01   99.42
2015-12-01   99.30
2016-01-01   98.88
2016-02-01   98.63
2016-03-01   98.62
2016-04-01   99.55
2016-05-01   99.24
2016-06-01   99.33
```

Y como estás creando un nuevo índice, por eso la siguiente línea de código incluye el nombre que se desea mostrar:

```
new_index = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='MS', name='Date')
```